# De-/Activatable Class Extensions in PHP

Tags: php, plugins, module, content-management-system, extend

i am working on a small CMS and ran over the following issue.
We are trying to create de-/activatable plugins, that will give the option to dynamically de- and activate features, like a special registration etc. I wanted to know if there are any best practices to accomplish this. Our first thought was to disable the extends of a php class if the module/plugin itself isnt active, but this seemed kinda dirty and we had no idea how to implement it.

I hope that someone can help us out.